# Want the metadata of PSD file while convert into PNG

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, metadata, psd

This is my code. I need the pdf file information as it when I am convert into PNG.

```
def convert_images():
    for file in glob.glob("*.PSD"):
        file, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        # print(file)
        file = file.split('\\')[-1]
        psd = PSDImage.open(file)
        psd.composite().save(directory + "\\" + file + ".png", "png")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    convert_images()
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Which metadata specifically are you referring to?

Comment: such as author name, resolution, color space, copyright, and keywords applied to it. For example, some basic information to an image file, such as height, width, file format. Etc this the metadata

Comment: All (non-raw) image formats (TIFF, JPEG, PNG, TGA, GIF) store image height and width anyway, so that's assumed. Photoshop can store keywords, author, copyright and colour profiles in Adobe-specific fields, in IPTC data, in EXIF-like data and/or in XMP sidecar files and not all of those can be stored within a PNG - so it would depend on your very specific needs and how your data is stored. If you are looking for a more compatible format, you might be better off with TIFF.

Comment: Example we use Image.info['exif'] while using PIL so I'm asking anything like that in psd_tools